# Using 12.04 LTS, Update Manager offers 12.10 but not 12.04.2

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

I'm running 12.04 LTS under VirtualBox for Mac, and I'm not getting an option for any upgrade to 12.04.2 in Update Manager. In Settings, "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" is set to "For long-term support versions". When I set it to "For any new version", I'm notified of 12.10. But cannot get it to offer 12.04.2 at all.

`lsb_release -a` in Terminal results in:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

The various terminal update options don't help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version 12.04.2 isn't a real version of Ubuntu, it is a meta version.
To avoid long waits for updates following a new installations of the LTS versions, Canonical is releasing new installation images every 6 months or so, to allow users to users to install the LTS version on new computers without having to deal with updating (almost) every single package in the system.

Comment: ...you might also suggest he run 'lsb_release -a'. That should show him he has what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the only chief difference between 12.04 and 12.04.2 is the updated packages. Which you already get from the update manager.